# Fix last element of ListView to the bottom of screen

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement a custom navigation drawer using Flutter. I would like to attach log out option to the bottom of the drawer. The problem is that number of elements above log out option is unknow (from 3 to 17).

So if these widgets take half of the space of a drawer, then log out option will be on the bottom, and if there is too much of them and you have to scroll to see them all, then the log out option will be simply the last.

I am also trying to give the first two options a green background color. Which widget tree would you recommend me? I had a thought about the [ListView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) widget, it takes List of widgets as an argument in constructor.

Therefore I can solve the different background color for the first two items. But I still can't figure out how to attach the log out option to the bottom. In this case it's at the bottom of drawer, but it can happen, that other options will be bigger than screen size and in that case, it should be placed at the bottom of whole list.

EDIT: I've add a design to the question. The logout option is the one called Odhlášení. In this case it's at the bottom of drawer, but it can happen, that other options will be bigger than the screen size and in that case, it should be placed at the bottom of whole list.

Design:
[image: Design example]

Comment: What have you tried? Any code?

Comment: Hey, I don't have any code yet. I am just thinking about the layout and I can't figure anything out. I also didn't ask for any specific code, all I need is a hint about what widgets to use.

Comment: You can always upload your image to an image hosting site (like [Imgur](http://imgur.com/)) and just attach the link to it.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I now understand what you mean @EllaGogo

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can simply use [ListView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) to manage the "17" navigation options. Wrap this `ListView` inside an [Column](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html). The `ListView` will be the first child of the `Column` the second child, therefore placing at the bottom, will be your logout action.

If you are using transparent widgets (like [ListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)) inside your `ListView` to display the navigation options, you can simply wrap it inside a [Container](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html). The `Container`, besides many other widgets, allows you to set a new background color with its `color` attribute.

Using this approach the widget tree would look like the following:

```
- Column                 // Column to place your LogutButton always below the ListView
  - ListView             // ListView to wrap all your navigation scrollable
    - Container          // Container for setting the color to green
      - GreenNavigation
    - Container
      - GreenNavigation
    - Navigation
    - Navigation
    - ...
  - LogOutButton
```

---

**Update 1 - Sticky LogOutButton :**
To achieve the `LogOutButton` sticking to the end of the `ListView` you'll neeed to do two things:

1. Replace the [Expanded](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) with an [Flexible](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)
2. Set `shrinkWrap: true` inside the `ListView`

---

**Update 2 - Spaced LogOutButton until large List:**
Achieving the described behavior is a more difficult step. You'll have to check if the `ListView` exceeds the screen and is scrollable.

To do this I wrote this short snippet:

```
  bool isListLarge() {
    return controller.positions.isNotEmpty && physics.shouldAcceptUserOffset(controller.position);
  }
```

It will return true if the `ListView` exceeds its limitations. Now we can refresh the state of the view, depending on the result of `isListViewLarge`. Below again a full code example.

---

Standalone code example (**Update 2: Spaced LogOutButton until large List**):

[image: Demo Update 2]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        drawer: MyDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDrawerState createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  ScrollPhysics physics = ScrollPhysics();

  int entries = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget logout = IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
        onPressed: () => {setState(() => entries += 4)});

    List<Widget> navigationEntries = List<int>.generate(entries, (i) => i)
        .map<Widget>((i) => ListTile(
              title: Text(i.toString()),
            ))
        .toList();

    if (this.isListLarge()) {  // if the List is large, add the logout to the scrollable list
      navigationEntries.add(logout);
    }

    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,  // place the logout at the end of the drawer
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: ListView(
              controller: controller,
              physics: physics,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: navigationEntries,
            ),
          ),
          this.isListLarge() ? Container() : logout // if the List is small, add the logout at the end of the drawer
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  bool isListLarge() {
    return controller.positions.isNotEmpty && physics.shouldAcceptUserOffset(controller.position);
  }
}
```

---

Standalone code example (**Update 1: Sticky LogOutButton**):

[image: Demo Updated]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        drawer: MyDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDrawerState createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {
  int entries = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: List<int>.generate(entries, (i) => i)
                  .map((i) => ListTile(
                        title: Text(i.toString()),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
              onPressed: () => {setState(() => entries += 4)})
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Standalone code example (**Old: Sticking to bottom**):

[image: Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        drawer: MyDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: List<int>.generate(40, (i) => i + 1)
                  .map((i) => ListTile(
                        title: Text(i.toString()),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app), onPressed: () => {})
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your answer, but it's not what I am trying to achieve. In your example log out option is above other options, I want it to be on the same layer as everything else. If other options on he list exceed screen height, then log out option will be last element on that list. But if there is let's say only 4 options, then log out option will still be the last, but also it will be attached to the bottom of the screen. Do you understand me?

Comment: Okay, no problem we can simply use `shrinkWrap`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: (and replace the `Expanded` with an `Flexible`

Comment: Thanks for update, we'll its definitely closer to what I want.. I managed to upload design of drawer to imgur. Here's the link https://imgur.com/a/nFK4ap0

Comment: So which questions leaves my answer open to you? I had a look at your design and the only real difference I see is the green background at the top?

Comment: The difference I see is in the initial state of your gif. The log out option sticks to the list instead of being attached to the bottom of the screen. This behavior you implemented is desired only if options before log out exceed the height of the screen.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to wrap IconButton in Alignment widget and set alignment to bottom left?

Comment: This makes it a bit more complicated, the `ListView` has an infnite height, therefore there is not bottom.

Comment: I am not a native speaker, so it's hard to explain what I want to achieve. If you could wait a few hours, I can upload more pictures that will show what I need. Because now I am probably just wasting your time as you try to implement things I don't need. Sorry for that.

Comment: I already understood what you are trying to achieve, I think I've found a solution. Give me 10min and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted! And I am glad that I asked, cause I would never figure this one out on my own.

Comment: Hey, so I've just implemented your solution for myself and found out, that it does not work, if you start with more items (e.g. entries = 20). For some reason controller.positions.isNotEmpty() returns false, and therefore also isListLarge() method. Any thoughts how to overcome this problem?

Comment: I'll have a look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer might be late, but this is for other people looking for another simple opinion in the same matter with a simple widget meant for that.

### **Short Answer:**

You can just use the [**Spacer**](https://youtu.be/7FJgd7QN1zI) widget which fills the remaining space automatically without the need to put your widgets on different layers.

### **Long Answer**:

You can still use a SizedBox with a height of double.maxFinite (which was the first thing I thought of) but it would throw your widget out of the viewport with a renderflex error so it's not that great in our scenario and we don't want any errors.

Or you can use a Stack widget and align your logout button in the bottomCenter, but we'd be adding more code to maintain.

So with these solutions there is always a catch.

#### Result

This is the full code of my drawer, feel free to use it as you like:

**Note**: Some might find it a bit excessive to separate the names, widgets and icons in separate maps, but this is my way of doing it since it becomes very painful to maintain the codebase when you have more pages or if you want to make quick changes the the name, the icons or the widgets, since the styling will get in the way and you'll have to scroll every time to find your ListTile.

So feel free to edit the code if you find the structure a bit overkill for your  scenario.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AppDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  AppDrawer({super.key});
  final Map<String, Widget> pages = {
      "Page 1": const Placeholder(),
      "Page 2": const Placeholder(),
      "Page 3": const Placeholder(),
      "Page 4": const Placeholder(),
      "Page 5": const Placeholder(),
    };
    final Map<String, IconData> icons = {
      "Page 1": Icons.home_filled,
      "Page 2": Icons.edit_document,
      "Page 3": CupertinoIcons.building_2_fill,
      "Page 4": Icons.all_inbox_rounded,
      "Page 5": CupertinoIcons.mail_solid,
    };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> drawerContent = [
      const UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
        accountName: Text("black-purple"),
        accountEmail: Text("blackpurpledev@gmail.com"),
        currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(),
      ),
      ...pages.keys
          .map(
            (page) => ListTile(
              title: Text(page),
              leading: Icon(
                icons[page],
              ),
              onTap: () => Get.to(pages[page]),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      const Spacer(),
      ListTile(
        title: const Text("Logout"),
        leading: const Icon(Icons.logout),
        onTap: () {},
      )
    ];
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(children: drawerContent),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Helpful packages I user while making this simple example (in case you still haven't had the chance to use them in one of your apps):

- [Responsive Sizer](https://pub.dev.packages/responsive_sizer)
  To get the exact amount of screen height or width you want (example: 20.h == 20% of screen height / 13.w == 13% of screen width)
- [GetX](https://pub.dev.packages/get)
  To easily navigate between pages with as simple as typing **Get.to(YourWidget())**

Here is a quick screenshot to show you the result I got.

[image]