# How to add a Spacer in a ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

Right now I am using a column to display several widgets:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Text('1'),
    Text('2'),
    Spacer(),
    Text('3'),
    Text('4'),
  ],
),
```

So the screen looks like this:

```
---
 1
 2



 3
 4
---
```

It allows me to always align `'1'` and `'2'` at the top and `'3'` and `'4'` at the bottom of my widget independently of its size.

---

However, when the widget becomes too small, it overflows:

```
---
 1
 2
 3
---
 4  // <- Overflow
```

Because of this, I would like to achieve the same result with a `ListView` so:

- When the widget is high enough, `'1'` `'2'` are top-aligned and `'3'` `'4'` are bottom-aligned.
- When the widget is not high enough, there is no extra space anymore between `'2'` and `'3'`, but the user can scroll down.

---

I couldn't manage to use a `Spacer` a `ListView`. It throws me the error:

```
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

---

What would be the correct way to implement it?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55393936/3123335

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to achieve. In the question you sent, the footer is "sticky"/"not scrollable", I want all my items to be scrollable

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Text('1') and Text('2') to a Column and Text('3') and Text('4') to another Column. Then add these two columns to an Expanded parent column and main axis alignment for the parent column as spaceBetween. Similar to the code below:

```
  Expanded(
    ParentColumn(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children:[
        Column1(
          children: [
            Text('1'),
            Text('2'),
           ],
        ),
        Column2(
          children: [
            Text('3'),
            Text('4'),
           ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Hello, but this wouldn't be scrollable if the widget is small right?

Answer (score 0):

I've create a widget for this exact purpose, below is the code snippet for the same, replace your `SingleChildScrollView` with `SpaceBetweenScrollView`, just use the `child` field for top part and `footer` field for the bottom part, and you're good to go.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SpaceBetweenScrollView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SpaceBetweenScrollView({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.footer,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final Widget footer;
  final EdgeInsets padding;

  @override
  State<SpaceBetweenScrollView> createState() => _SpaceBetweenScrollViewState();
}

class _SpaceBetweenScrollViewState extends State<SpaceBetweenScrollView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: widget.padding,
        keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          constraints: constraints.copyWith(
            minHeight: constraints.maxHeight - (widget.padding.top + widget.padding.bottom),
            maxHeight: double.infinity,
          ),
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [widget.child, widget.footer],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```