# How can I stick the last element of List to the bottom of the but push it down when required?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to create a ListView, where the last child is positioned at the bottom  of the screen, even if the rest of the content is smaller. If the rest of the content grows larger than the available space, or if the available size is reduced, the bottom child should be pushed down (Kind of like `position: sticky` in CSS).

My problem is almost exactly the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55392459/fix-last-element-of-listview-to-the-bottom-of-screen). The only difference is that the number of children in my list can change dynamically, and the solution proposed in the linked question does not handle that.

I have the following solution, but there are some problems with it. Each time the state is updated, the bottom child flashes, and another problem is that setState is called continiously.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class ListWithBottomChild extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListWithBottomChild({
    required this.children,
    required this.bottomChild,
    this.padding = EdgeInsets.zero,
  });

  final List<Widget> children;
  final Widget bottomChild;
  final EdgeInsets padding;

  @override
  _ListWithBottomChildState createState() => _ListWithBottomChildState();
}

class _ListWithBottomChildState extends State<ListWithBottomChild> {
  ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  bool _isLarge = true;

  late List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    children = widget.children;

    SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (_controller.hasClients) {
        setState(() {
          _isLarge = _controller.position.maxScrollExtent > 0;
        });
      }

      if (!children.contains(widget.bottomChild) && _isLarge) {
        children.add(widget.bottomChild);
      }
    });

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _controller,
            padding: widget.padding,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: children,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        if (!_isLarge) widget.bottomChild
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Another idea that I have is to use a dynamically sized spacer before the bottom child, but I can't figure out a way to set the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write

```
Column(
  children: children..add(widget.bottomChild)
)
```

I think this could solve it.